# hovering two hover elements at a same time

Tags: css, hover, less

Hi i am stuck in a problem..
I have a css code...

```
.inner-inline .game-main:hover, .game-main strong a:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Here i want that ".game-main" which is a div on hovering it, it changes color of the text, but i also wanna hover the element inside it which is an anchor tag at same time div hovers...
I have googled this, may be [LESS](http://lesscss.org) is the solution but i cant fix the eligible code for it...

Please could you help..??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ":hover" pseudo-class does not need to be the last part of the css selector. You can do stuff like:

```
.game-main:hover, .game-main:hover a {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Without seeing your html it's hard to be more precise.